# CSS3 match shape in 3d (top of cube)

Tags: css, 3d, shapes

I am not good in math and geometry, so I would love if someone could help me with creating the following shape:

[image: shape]

So basically the shape exists out of 3 rectangles, I got the first two working perfect with transform matrix, but I can't get the last one to match the shape (see link above for img)

[JSFiddle, what I tried so far or see code below](http://jsfiddle.net/5hGtP/)

HTML

```
<div class="shape">
  <div class="shape-rect-one"></div>
  <div class="shape-rect-two"></div>
  <div class="shape-rect-three"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.shape {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.shape div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  background-color: #333;
}

.shape-rect-one {
  z-index: 100;

  transform: matrix(1, -0.40, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix(1, -0.40, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

.shape-rect-two {
  z-index: 200;

  transform: matrix(1, -0.40, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0.40, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

.shape-rect-three {
  z-index: 300;
}​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5hGtP/7/ is kinda close.

Comment: @Shmiddty how can I fix these differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should create the diamond shape.

```
transform: matrix(-0.965, 0.45, -0.965, -0.45, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform: matrix(-0.965, 0.45, -0.965, -0.45, 0, 0);
```

Comment: btw the size is not equal anymore, if I put them on each other the diamont is about 5px bigger (up and down)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in a much simpler manner, with only one element.

## [***DEMO***](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/DmklE)

**Result**:

[image: 6 point star]

**HTML**:

```
<div class='piece'></div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.piece {
  width: 10em; height: 8.66em; /* 10*sqrt(3)/2 = 8.66 */
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.piece {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
}
.piece:before, .piece:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit; height: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
}
.piece:before { transform: skewX(-30deg) skewX(-30deg); }
.piece:after { transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(-60deg) skewX(-30deg); }
```